# Getting socket.io to reconnect when re-entering the page with the back button

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

everyone -

I have a feature I'm trying to add to a Node.js application that uses socket.io (4.x, if it matters). I am creating a game where I would like the user to reconnect to their existing game if they disconnect and then reconnect.

Reconnecting works fine if you refresh the page. However, if, for example, I navigate somewhere else and then hit the back button, the reconnection does not happen. For example, just to test it out, I have:

```js
/*Server side:*/
socket.on('connection',(socket)=> {
  const pinger = setInterval(() => {
    io.to(socket.id).emit('ping', null);
  }, 1000);
  ...etc...
}

/*Client side:*/
const socket = io();
socket.on('ping',(data)=> {
  console.log('ping');
});
```

What I see is a "ping" event every second (as expected). I go to a different page, and then hit the back button. The page re-renders, but the "ping" event does not come back. After around 30 seconds, the connection re-establishes, but I would like it to try to re-establish immediately.

Is there an easy way to force the game to re-establish the connection to the server sooner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quick addendum - I hit the back button, and after around 30 seconds, the browser automatically re-established the connection. This is...fine, but not ideal - is there any way I can get it to try to re-establish immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the exact same problem and my solution was to add a listener to the `pageshow` event (with the 'e' argument in the callback), then check the value of `e.persisted`, and if `e.persisted` equals true (means that current page load is not an initial load) I then call `window.location.reload()` to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same exact problem and wanted to find a solution without refreshing the page and this ended up working for me.

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function (event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
    socket.disconnect();
    socket = null;
    initiateConnection();
  }
});

$(document).ready(initiateConnection());

function initiateConnection() {

  var socket = io(window.location.host, {
    rememberTransport: false,
    transports: ["websocket"],
  });
}
```

I am using flask-socketIO on the server side if that makes any difference.